# Knit rscript to pdf internally

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am creating a CL Rscript which uses optparse to take flag inputs. At the end of this script, I want to be able to knit to a pdf while conserving the user inputs as variables.

Adding the `rmarkdown::render()` command by itself causes a recursion error, and adding in

`` #' `rmarkdown::render()` `` does nothing when run as a whole.

Ideally, this generates a knitted pdf with all figures shown next to the code that generated them, and I'd be able to display the variable input values with print statements next to the graphing functions.

Comment: Without more information it's hard to give a real answer. If I understand you correctly, this may be what you want: 
Make it two files – one knitr (*.Rnw) file that defines your desired analysis output and a second file that's simply an R script that takes the command line options, puts them in appropriate variables and then runs knitr on the Rnw file.

Comment: I'm trying to run a seurat analysis in a .R file that takes in flags for variables. Ideally, one of those flags can give the command to retrieve a knitted Rscript rather than just the pdf output of all graphs. Do you know if .Rnw files are able to be run outside of RStudio from the command line?

Comment: I am not sure I totally understand your desired workflow – maybe you should elaborate on this a bit in your question.. Anyway, R-Studio is absolutely not required for knitr: In fact, I don't use r-studio but plain vanilla R plus vim for my editor. You can write an R-Script that does `foo <- mycomplicatedcomputation(); library(knitr); knit("something.Rnw")` and call it from the command line.